# how to handle two dimensional dict in python?

Tags: python

input data

```
{'NOMSEXITInterview__INTTYPE_2': u'2',
 'NOMSEXITInterview__INTDUR_2': u'3',
 'NOMSEXITInterview__GENDER_2': u'3', 
 'NOMSEXITInterview__EMPLOY_2': u'6',
 'Referral__referral_type': u'food', 
 'Referral__ok_to_mail': u'False', 
 'Referral__okay_to_call': u'False',
 'Referral__okay_to_leave_message': u'True',
 'data_model_name': ['NOMSEXITInterview', 'Referral']}
```

i want to  output below define format

```
{'NOMSEXITInterview':{'INTTYPE_2':'2','INTDUR_2':'3','GENDER_2','EMPLOY_2':'6'}}  
{'Referral':{'referral_type':'food',...}}
```

and so on

any idea?????

Comment: header_name = model_all.split("__")
                   #module field name
                   header_set.append(header_name[1])
                   #module name
                   module_name.append(header_name[0])

 now i want to store  fields in model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'NOMSEXITInterview__INTTYPE_2': u'2',
 'NOMSEXITInterview__INTDUR_2': u'3',
 'NOMSEXITInterview__GENDER_2': u'3', 
 'NOMSEXITInterview__EMPLOY_2': u'6',
 'Referral__referral_type': u'food', 
 'Referral__ok_to_mail': u'False', 
 'Referral__okay_to_call': u'False',
 'Referral__okay_to_leave_message': u'True',
 'data_model_name': ['NOMSEXITInterview', 'Referral']}

result = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    parts = k.split("__")
    if len(parts) == 2:
        result.setdefault(parts[0], {})[parts[1]] = v
    else:
        result[k] = v
print result
```

**Output**

```
{'Referral': {'referral_type': u'food', 'ok_to_mail': u'False', 'okay_to_call': u'False', 'okay_to_leave_message': u'True'},
 'data_model_name': ['NOMSEXITInterview', 'Referral'],
 'NOMSEXITInterview': {'INTTYPE_2': u'2', 'INTDUR_2': u'3', 'GENDER_2': u'3', 'EMPLOY_2': u'6'}}
```